# Route.delete() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have node-express app where I have bunch of Routes for login, logout and signup and one Route for checking authorised Route which can be accessed only through providing authToken. I moved the Routes to separate Route file and I got the above error.

This is my Users Routes File:

```
const express = require('express');
const authenticate = require('./../middleware/authenticate');
const router = express.Router();
const {User} = require('./../models/user');

    router.post('/',(req, res) => {
    var body = _.pick(req.body,['email','password']);
    var user = new User(body);


    user.save().then(() => {
       return user.generateAuthToken()
    }).then((token) => {
        res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});


router.post('/login',(req, res) => {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
    User.findByCredentials(body.email, body.password).then((user) => {
        return user.generateAuthToken().then((token) => {
            res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
        });
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});

router.delete('/logout',authenticate, (req, res) => {
    req.user.removeToken(req.token).then(() => {
        res.status(200).send();
    },(e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }) ;
});


router.get('/me',authenticate, (req,res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
});


module.exports = router;
```

Following is my main server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const _ = require('lodash');
var app = express();
const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users');

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/users', usersRoutes);

var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {User} = require('./models/user');
var {authenticate} = require('./middleware/authenticate');


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000 ;
app.listen(port, () =>  console.log(`Listening on ${port}...`))
```

I have a model/Schema(mongoose) file for User so If You feel you need that I am ready to edit my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `router.delete` is expecting a function on the middleware parameter (like you did in your server.js file with `app.use(express.json())`) so it can be used like a callback which gets called whenever a request reach your route.

Try changing `authenticate` to `authenticate()`.

It seems like in your users routes file you are importing the entire module who contains the authenticate function, so when try to access it like a function you'll get an error. You need to import it like you did in your server.js file.

Change the line `const authenticate = require('./../middleware/authenticate');` for `const {authenticate} = require('./../middleware/authenticate');`.

Comment: can you answer fully so others can benefit , your answer is not specifically describing

Comment: I tried router.delete('/logout',authenticate(), (req, res) => {
    req.user.removeToken(req.token).then(() => {
        res.status(200).send();
    },(e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }) ;
});

i got this following error : authenticate is not a function

Comment: Seems like in your users routes file you are importing the entire module who contains the authenticate function, so when try to access it like a function you got an error. You need to import it like you did in your server.js file.

Comment: Change `const authenticate = require('./../middleware/authenticate');` for `const {authenticate} = require('./../middleware/authenticate');`.